# convert time to UTC in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, utc

I have multiple csv files, I've set DateTime as the index.

```
df6.set_index("gmtime", inplace=True)
#correct the underscores in old datetime format
df6.index = [" ".join( str(val).split("_")) for val in df6.index]
df6.index = pd.to_datetime(df6.index)
```

[image]

The time was put in GMT, but I think it's been saved as BST (British summertime) when I set the clock for raspberry pi.
I want to shift the time one hour backwards. When I use

```
df6.tz_convert(pytz.timezone('utc'))
```

it gives me below error as it assumes that the time is correct.

> Cannot convert tz-naive timestamps, use tz_localize to localize

How can I shift the time to one hour?

Comment: if you want to improve the quality of the answers (make them more specific), please make sure to add sample data as text, not image.

Comment: regarding the question: are you sure that *all* your data is recorded with the BST UTC offset (+1h)? Or is DST accounted for, i.e. during winter, you would have UTC+0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a column that contains date/time info as string, you would convert to datetime, localize to a time zone (here: Europe/London), then convert to UTC. You can do that before you set as index.

Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

dti = pd.to_datetime(["2021-09-01"]).tz_localize("Europe/London").tz_convert("UTC")

print(dti) # notice 1 hour shift:
# DatetimeIndex(['2021-08-31 23:00:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)
```

Note: setting a *time zone* means that DST is accounted for, i.e. here, during winter you'd have UTC+0 and during summer UTC+1.

Answer (score 5):

To add to FObersteiner's response (sorry,new user, can't comment on answers yet):

I've noticed that in all the real world situations I've run across it (with full dataframes or pandas series instead of just a single date), .tz_localize() and .tz_convert() need to be called slightly differently.

What's worked for me is

```
df['column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column']).dt.tz_localize('Europe/London').dt.tz_convert('UTC')
```

Without the .dt, I get "index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex."

Comment: jup, for pd.Series (df columns), you need to use the [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html). If you're dealing with and index (as I do in my anwer), you can't use it. Kind of confusing.